# Create new user in DCL-935 firmware

Tags: users, firmware, passwd

For an assignment for school, I am investigating a dlink IP cam firmware for vulnerabilities.

In the emulation I can see there is a user called admin. in the /etc/passwd I can see the password (blank).

Is it possible to add a new user within the emulation?

So far, I have created a new user with the echo command and I have used a Base64 encryption, just like what happened with the admin account.

Now I want to give that account a password so I can log in to the web interface.

So far I have used echo to add the credentials to the passwd file, in the same syntax that was used for the admin account (admin::0:0:0 etc etc).

However, when I go to the webinterface and use the account I created with the password I have created (blank), it gives me back a '401 Unauthorized'.

When I restart the emulation and use 'cat' on the passwd file, the new created password has disappeared from that list.